# Kendo UI Grid Read Action is not being called when hosted on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Ive seen lots of traffic regarding this issue so I thought I would add my own spin.  Everything works as expected on my dev machine.  But when I deploy to Azure, the read action on the grid is no longer posted. instead its posting to the url of the page.

Here is my grid

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<HondaPERebates.Model.Models.ClaimModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Groupable()
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.RebateProgramId).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Status).ClientTemplate("<span class='#=GetClass(Status)#'>#=Status#</span>").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SellingDealerNo).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SerialNumberSuffix).ClientTemplate("<span>#=SerialNumberPrefix#-#=SerialNumberSuffix#</span>").Width(150).Title("Serial Number").Filterable(false);
            columns.Bound(p => p.SubmittedDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(75);
        })
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .Selectable()
        .Filterable()
        .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true).Height(630))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.RebateProgramId);
            })
                .PageSize(65)
                .Read(read => read.Action("_GetClaims", "Rebates").Data("grid_Parameters"))
            )
                .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound")
            )
        )
```

and the controller

```
 public ActionResult _GetClaims(int rebateProgramId, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var email = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        var list = _manager.GetClaimsByEmail(rebateProgramId, email);

        return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and the js that gets invoked to get extra parms

```
function grid_Parameters() {
    var RebateProgramId = $('#RebateProgramId').val();

    return { RebateProgramId: RebateProgramId };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case the Action method was not getting called (example : HierarchyBinding_Employees).

I changed the Name to GetHierarchyDataForEmployees and it worked for me :).